# Why am I unable to send mail using laravel 8 gmail smtp?

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, smtp, laravel-8

I'm trying to send a mail from my localhost laravel 8 app using Gmail SMTP after entering the configurations but keep getting

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

I have turned on the Less Secure App settings on my gmail and even downloaded cacert.pem and added the location to my php.ini but it just keeps loading after submitting the form and then giving me the above error. What do I need to do to get it to work?

**Here are my related .env file settings**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmailaddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mygmailaddress
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**mail.php**

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

**php.ini**

```
openssl.cafile=C:\wamp64\ssl\cacert.pem
openssl.capath=C:\wamp64\ssl
```

Maybe I'm supposed to change something in my mail.php file? Or just one of the fields in the php.ini should be present?
I've tried to change the smtp mail host, port and encryption to smtp.gmail.com, 465, and ssl in mail.php respectively, but that didn't work either. Neither did changing .env port to 587 and encryption TLS. What am I missing? Please help.

Fairly new to Laravel though, please be nice lol.

Comment: The error clearly states that your certificate store is not set up correctly, so the hostname cannot be properly verified. Did you restart the PHP server after making changes to the CA bundle location?

Comment: And where did you add the location in php.ini?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I restarted it afterwards and still getting the same error. The line involved looks like this: `openssl.cafile=C:\wamp64\ssl\cacert.pem`

Comment: Where did you get the CA bundle from? Does output from `phpinfo()` via your web server confirm the change in configuration settings?

Comment: @miken32 It's one I downloaded back earlier in January I copied from an old device. Where can I get an updated CA bundle? Yes the phpinfo() shows the location of the cacert.pem I entered.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: @miken32 Sigh. Same thing, man. I'm frustrated at this point

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest then. Your Laravel config looks fine, either 465/ssl or 587/tls should work. I'd always suggest working on Linux/UNIX for this sort of thing, but if you're stuck on Windows make sure firewalls and antivirus are disabled. You can try running `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587` at the command line to ensure you're not getting caught by some proxy or AV software.

Comment: Have you enabled two step verification in your gmail account?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to change MAIL_PORT=587 . After than you need to give permission in your account to [Less secure apps.](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)